# Issue loading content into DIV with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm out of ideas and have been searching for awhile now, so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a select box that allows a user to select a specific value. Then try to load a page using the URL/value and keep receiving a blank page.

Assuming no value is passed, it works. I've used this page in the same way quite a number of times in the past so I'm not certain whats wrong. Also, it only seems to fail if specific URL parameters are passed.  I remove a substantial amount of code outside of the problem area to make it a bit easier to read.

So 
$('#sheetDiv').load('loaddates.php');
will work
and 
$('#sheetDiv').load('loaddates.php?project_name=' + value);
will not

**Code for main page is below:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('db.php');

if($_POST[submit]=="Submit")
{

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblusers SET username='".$_POST[username]."',password='".$_POST[password]."',type='".$_POST[type]."'") or print mysql_error();
}
function make_star($x)
{
    $s="";
    for($i=1;$i<=strlen($x);$i++)
    {
        $s.="*";
    }
    return $s;
}
?>

<head>
<script language="javascript" src="jscript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/facefiles/jquery-1.2.2.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/ddaccordion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jscript/jmenu.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" src="jscript/user.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="jscript/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendarDateInput.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function selectProject() {
    $('#selectProject').show();
    $('#addProject').hide();
}
function selectDate() {
    $('#addProject').hide();
    $('#selectDate').show();
    }
function pdelete(id)
{
    if(confirm('Are sure to delete the data ?')==true)
    {
    $.ajax({
                           type: "GET",
                           url: "ajax.php",
                           data: "act=delete&tbl=timesheet"+"&id="+id,
                           success: function(result){
                             $(".error").html(result);
                             setTimeout('window.location.reload()',2000);
                        }
    });
    }   


}
checked=false;
function checkedAll (myfrm) {
    var aa= document.getElementById('frm');
     if (checked == false)
          {
           checked = true
          }
        else
          {
          checked = false
          }
    for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length; i++) 
    {
     aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
    }
      }

function del() 
         {
               var flag=false;
                var pass ;
                 for(var i=0; i<document.frm.length; i++) //check for all checkboxes
                 {
                   if( document.frm.elements[i].type=="checkbox" && document.frm.elements[i].checked==true )
                   {
                        flag=true;

                   }
                 }
                    if(flag == true)
                    {
                      if(confirm("Do you sure to delete this?"))
                      {
                      return true;
                      }else
                      { return false;
                      }
                    }


                 if( flag==false )  // if no checkbox selected
                 {
                       alert("Please select at least one checkbox to proceed.");
                       return false;
                 }
        }

function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) {
  window.open(theURL,winName,features);
  return false;
}
function loadUsers(id) {
if(id !=2) {
var value = $('#selectValue').val();
alert('loadates2.php?project_name=' + value);
$('#sheetDiv').load('loaddates.php?project_name=' + value);

}
else if(id == 2) {
var value = $('#f_new_age_date').val();
$('#sheetDiv').load('loaddates.php?project_date=' + value);
}
}

function addProject() {
$('#selectProject').hide();
$('#selectDate').hide();
$('#addProject').show();
}
</script>
<style>
.selectday{
    border-right:#CBCBCB 1px solid;
    border-left:#CBCBCB 1px solid;
    border-bottom:#CBCBCB 1px solid;
    border-top:#CBCBCB 1px solid;
    color:#666;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    }
    .selectedday{
    border-right:#CBCBCB 1px solid;
    border-left:#CBCBCB 1px solid;
    border-bottom:#CBCBCB 1px solid;
    border-top:#CBCBCB 1px solid;
    color:#666;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-top:7px;
    }
    .sday
    {
        color:#f69929;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:24px;
        font-weight:bold;
        }
</style>
<link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="images/calendar.css" title="win2k-cold-1">
<!-- main calendar program -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="images/calendar.js"></script>
    <!-- language for the calendar -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="images/calendar-en.js"></script>
<!-- the following script defines the Calendar.setup helper function, which makes
          adding a calendar a matter of 1 or 2 lines of code. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="images/calendar-setup.js"></script>

</head>
<div id="newContainer">

<?php if($_SESSION[usertype] == "A" || $_SESSION[usertype] == "S" ) { ?>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<table width="100%" style="position:relative; left:15px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <?php include('header_project.php');?>
 <tr>
    <td  align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center"><div id="result" align="center" style="color:#FF0000; display:block;">&nbsp;</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="15%" height="395" align="left" valign="top" colspan="2"><? include('menu.php')?></td>
        <td width="100%"  valign="top">
          < <div id="form_news"  style="width:850px; position:relative;left:52px;">

<div id="options" style="margin-left: 350px;margin-top:130px;position:absolute;z-index:2">        
<a href="#" onclick="addProject()">Add New</a>   |  <a href="#" onclick="selectProject()">Select Project </a>
</div>
<div id="addProject" style="padding-top:15px; padding: 5px; display:none; height:500px; width:950px;position:relative; top:15px;">
<table width="100%" style="position:relative; left:25px" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                 <tr><td colspan="8"> 
                 <form name="ff1" method="post" action="time.php">
                  <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3"> 

                  <tr align="left">
               <tr>

                    <td width="86" align="left" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" class="login_fnt"><span class="text_pt space">Project</span></td>
                    <td width="86" align="left" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" class="login_fnt"><span class="text_pt space">Work Code</span></td>
                    <td width="90" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" ><span class="text_pt space">Employee Name</span></td>
                    <td width="44" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" ><span class="text_pt space"> Billable Hours</span></td>
                    <td width="147" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" ><span class="text_pt space">Notes</span></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" ><span class="text_pt space">Date</span></td>
                    <td  >&nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
                  <tr align="left">
                    <td width="132" valign="top" class="f12b"><select name="project_number" id="project_name">
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <?php
                    $aa=mysql_query("select * from projects");
                    while($sql=mysql_fetch_array($aa))
                    {
                ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $sql['project_number']?>" ><?php echo $sql['project_name']?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
              </select></td>
                    <td width="127" valign="top" class="f12b"><select name="task" id="task">
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <?php
                    $aa=mysql_query("select * from work_codes");
                    while($sql=mysql_fetch_array($aa))
                    {
                ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $sql['work_codes']?>"><?php echo $sql['work_codes']?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select> </td>
                    <td width="111" valign="top" class="login_fnt"><select name="staff_name" id="staff_name">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <?php
                    $aa=mysql_query("select * from staff_members");
                    while($sql_clients=mysql_fetch_array($aa))
                    {
                ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $sql_clients['staff_id']?>" ><?php echo $sql_clients['staff_name']?></option>
                <?php } ?>
          </select></td>
                    <td width="47" valign="top" class="f12b"><input type="text" name="bill_hours" id="bill_hours" value="" size="5" /></td>
                    <td width="136" valign="top" class="f12b"><textarea name="description" id="description" cols="20" rows="1"></textarea>
                    <input type="hidden" name="expense_date" value="<?php echo $currdate;?>" />                    </td>
                    <td width="185" valign="top" class="f12b">
                    <?php
                    $currdate=date('Y-m-d');
                    ?>
                    <input name="new_age_date" id="f_new_age_date" onChange="document.form_news.new_rem_age_date.value=document.form_news.new_age_date.value" size="10" readonly="yes" type="text" value="<?php echo $currdate;?>"> 
              <img src="images/img.gif" id="trigger_new_age_date" style="cursor: pointer; border: medium none;" title="Select Date"> 
              <script type="text/javascript">
    Calendar.setup({
            inputField     :    "f_new_age_date",         
            ifFormat       :    "%Y-%m-%d",     
            button         :    "trigger_new_age_date",   
            singleClick    :    true                       
        });
          </script>                    </td>
                    <td width="41" valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr align="left">
                    <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="login_fnt">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr align="left">
                    <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="login_fnt">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="f12b"></td>
                    <td valign="top" class="f12b"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add Time" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
              </form>
               </td></tr>
            </table>
</div>

<div id="selectProject" style="position:relative; z-index:1; padding-top:15px; padding: 5px; display:none; height:500px; width:950px; top:125px;">
<div style="position:relative;bottom:45px">
<p style="padding:5px padding-bottom:0px;margin-left:50px; "> Select a Project:<p>
<select id ="selectValue" style="margin-left:50px;position:relative;bottom:15px;width:150px;">
<?php 
$aa1 = mysql_query("select * from projects");
while(@$sql=mysql_fetch_array($aa1)) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $sql[project_name]; ?>"><?php echo $sql[project_name]; ?> </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<input type="button" id="selectProjectSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="loadUsers()" style="position:relative;bottom:15px;"/>


</div>
<div id="sheetDiv" style="height:500px;width:950px; border: solid 1px red; position:relative; bottom:70px;"> random </div>
</div>

</td></tr> 
                </table>  
                </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

    </table></td>
  </tr>


<?php }?>

</div>





*****Code for loaded div below:*******






<?php
session_start();
include('db.php');
?>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateField(id, field, project_name, date) {
if(id) {
    $field = $('#'+id);
    $value = $field.val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax2.php",
        data: "rqt=time&idfield=" + id + "&valuefield="+$value });
}
else {

        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax2.php",
        data: "rqt=updatetime&valuefield="+ field + "&date=" + date + "&project_name=" + project_name});
}
}
function doit(id,fieldtype, newvalue) {
if(fieldtype=="staff_name" || fieldtype=="task"){
var newvalue = newvalue.options[newvalue.selectedIndex].value;
}


$.ajax({
                           type: "GET",
                           url: "ajax2.php",
                           data: "fieldtype=" + fieldtype + "&id=" + id + "&newvalue=" + newvalue,
                           });
}
</script>
</head>


<?php if($_REQUEST[project_date]){
$currDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_REQUEST[project_date]));
$dayOfWeek = date('N', strtotime($_REQUEST[project_date]));
if($dayOfWeek == 7) { $dayOfWeek = 0;}
$subtractTime = "-".(string)$dayOfWeek."days";
$newdate = strtotime($subtractTime , strtotime ($currDate) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );

$enddate = $newdate;
}
?>
<?php
if($_SESSION[usertype] == "E") { ?>
<table width="875px"  style="position:relative; left:15px;" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">


                   <td colspan="8"> 
                 <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3"> 
               <tr>

                    <td width="100" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" class="login_fnt"><span class="text_pt space">Project Name</span></td>
                    <td width="100" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" ><span class="text_pt space">Sunday</span></td>
                    <td width="100" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" class="login_fnt"><span class="text_pt space">Monday</span></td>
                    <td width="100" align="left" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" class="login_fnt"><span class="text_pt space">Tuesday</span></td>
                    <td width="100" align="left" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" class="login_fnt"><span class="text_pt space">Wednesday</span></td>
                    <td width="100" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" ><span class="text_pt space">Thursday</span></td>
                    <td width="100" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" ><span class="text_pt space">Friday</span></td>
                    <td width="100" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" ><span class="text_pt space">Saturday</span></td>
               </tr>
              <?php  
               $totalhrs=0;
               $Query_dbl=mysql_query("select * from projects");
                while($dbl_=mysql_fetch_array($Query_dbl))
                            {
                            $counter = 0;
                            ?>  <?php
                            $secondCounter = 0;
                            $starting = true;
                            while($secondCounter != 7 ) {
                            $newdate = $enddate;
                            $newdate = strtotime("".$secondCounter."day" , strtotime($newdate));
                            $newdate = date("Y-m-d", $newdate);
                            $Query_fql=mysql_query("select * from timesheet where staff_name='".$_SESSION['staff_id']."' AND project_name='".$dbl_['project_name']."'");
                            if($secondCounter == 0 && mysql_num_rows($Query_fql) > 0 ) {
                            $PN_=mysql_fetch_array($Query_fql);
                            ?>
                            <tr> <td> <?php echo $PN_['project_name']; ?> 
                            </td>
                            <?php $starting = false;}
                            $Query_sql=mysql_query("select * from timesheet where staff_name='".$_SESSION['staff_id']."' AND project_name='".$dbl_['project_name']."' AND expense_date='".$newdate."'");
                            $Query_xql=mysql_query("select * from timesheet where staff_name='".$_SESSION['staff_id']."' AND project_name='".$dbl_['project_name']."' AND expense_date='".$newdate."'");
                            $secondCounter++;
                            if(mysql_num_rows($Query_xql) > 0) {
                            $currentDate = null;                            
                            while($sql_=mysql_fetch_array($Query_sql))
                            {
                                 if($currentDate != $sql_['expense_date']){
                                    $currentDate = $sql_['expense_date'];
                                    $cyell = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(bill_hours) AS newhours FROM timesheet WHERE expense_date='".$sql_['expense_date']."' and project_name='".$sql_['project_name']."' and staff_name='".$_SESSION['staff_id']."'");
                                    $cardyell=mysql_fetch_assoc($cyell);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                    continue;
                                    }
                  ?>

                    <td align="left"> 
                    <select style="width:100px" name="billHours" id="<?php echo $sql_['id'] ?>" onchange="updateField(this.id)">
                    <?php $a = 0; while($a != 15) {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $a; ?>" <?php if($sql_['bill_hours'] == $a) { echo "selected"; } ?>> <?php echo $a; ?> </option>
                    <?php $a = $a + .5;} ?>

                    </select>
</td>
                    <?php $totalhrs += $sql_['bill_hours']; } } else{ if($starting == false) { ?> <td>



                    <select style="width:100px" name="billHours" id="" onchange="updateField(null, this.value, <?php echo "'".$dbl_['project_name']."'";?>, <?php echo "'".$newdate."'";?>)">
                    <?php $a = 0; while($a != 15) {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $a; ?>" <?php if($sql_['bill_hours'] == $a) { echo "selected"; } ?>> <?php echo $a; ?> </option>
                    <?php $a = $a + .5;} ?>

                    </select>



                     </td> <?php }  } ?> 
                  <?php } ?> </tr> <?php }
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="top" class="f12b"><br/><strong>Total Hours</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" class="f12b">
                      <strong>
                        <?php
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo $totalhrs;
                    ?>
                      </strong></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="7" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>


                  </table>
                </td></tr> 
                </table>

</div>
<?php } 
if($_SESSION[usertype] == "S" || $_SESSION[usertype] == "A"){ ?>

<table width="875px"  style="position:relative;left:15px; bottom:0px !important" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">


                   <td colspan="8"> 
                 <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3"> 
               <tr>
                    <td width="20" class="login_fnt"><span class="text_pt space">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
                    <td width="160" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" class="login_fnt"><span class="text_pt space">Employee Name</span></td>
                    <td width="86" align="left" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" class="login_fnt"><span class="text_pt space">Date Worked</span></td>
                    <td width="86" align="left" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" class="login_fnt"><span class="text_pt space">Billable Hours</span></td>
                    <td width="90" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" ><span class="text_pt space">Work Code</span></td>
                    <td width="44" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" ><span class="text_pt space">Notes</span></td>
               </tr>
               <?php
                        $Query_sql=mysql_query("select * from timesheet where project_name='".$_REQUEST['project_name']."'");
                        $totalhrs=0;
                        while($sql_=mysql_fetch_array($Query_sql))
                        {

                  ?>
                  <tr>
 <td width="20" align="left" valign="top">
                    <a  href="time.php?del=del&id=<?php echo $sql_['id']?>" class="text_pt" style="position:relative; left:12px; title="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"><img src="redx.png" border="0" /></a></td>
<td width="90" align="left" valign="top" class="login_fnt"><select onchange="doit(<?php echo $sql_['id']?>, 'staff_name', this)" name="staff_name" id="staff_name">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <?php
                    $aa=mysql_query("select * from staff_members");
                    while($sql_clients=mysql_fetch_array($aa))
                    {
                ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $sql_clients['staff_id']?>" <?php if($sql_clients['staff_id']==$sql_['staff_name']) echo "selected";?>><?php echo $sql_clients['staff_name']?></option>
                <?php } ?>
          </select></td>

        <td width="90" align="left" valign="top" class="login_fnt"> <input id="text" onblur="doit(<?php echo $sql_['id']?>, 'expense_date', this.value)" value="<?php echo $sql_['expense_date'];?>"/></td> 



                    <td width="44" align="left" valign="top" class="f12b"><input type="text" onblur="doit(<?php echo $sql_['id']?>, 'bill_hours', this.value)" name="bill_hours" id="bill_hours" value="<?php echo $sql_['bill_hours']?>" size="5" />
                    <?php
                    $totalhrs=$totalhrs+$sql_['bill_hours'];
                    ?>                    
                    </td>
 <td width="86" align="left" valign="top" class="f12b"><select name="task" id="task" onchange="doit(<?php echo $sql_['id']?>, 'task', this)">
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <?php
                    $aa=mysql_query("select * from program_list");
                    while($sql=mysql_fetch_array($aa))
                    {
                ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $sql['id']?>" <?php if($sql['id']==$sql_['task']) echo "selected";?>><?php echo $sql['sports']?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select> </td>

                    <td width="147" align="left" valign="top" class="f12b"><textarea name="description" onblur="doit(<?php echo $sql_['id']?>, 'description', this.value)" style="height:20px" id="description" cols="20" rows="1"><?php echo $sql_['description']?></textarea></td>
                  </tr><?php  $i++; }  
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="top" class="f12b"><br/><strong>Total Hours</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" class="f12b">
                      <strong>
                        <?php
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo $totalhrs;
                    ?>
                      </strong></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="f12b">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="7" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>


                  </table>
                </td></tr> 
                </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: There are some javascript syntax errors such as a missing `)`, but there's so much code there I don't know where to begin. Confirm that `value` contains what you expect it to and that the php page returns what you expect it to and that it is well-formed (proper opening and matching closing tags/quotes).  Is that really jQuery 1.2.2? It looks like you are including jQuery twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a different approach to send parameters:

```
$("#sheetDiv").load("loaddates.php", { "project_name": value } );
```

That should do the job!

Comment: It certainly did, thank you so much, have no idea how much trouble it was causing me. Self taught so I have seemingly picked up a few bad habits along the way.

Comment: I'm also a self taught programmer! Started with C and now have advanced to Web development and HTML5. My friendly advice to you is to always to keep the documentation open whenever you are writing a sensitive program to get things done perfectly.